# How to calculate values of capacitor and resistor for Flyback converter?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I am designing a flyback converter in Matlab Simulink but I don't know how to calculate the values of the capacitor and resistor used in flyback converter.

Can anyone please help me with that?

[image: simplified circuit diagram]

Comment: If the comment was about only *one* of the two, I'd have considered some helpful hint, but like this, I cannot...

Comment: It's funny, R is the load, it depends on you.

Comment: [Flyback converter help page](http://www.stades.co.uk/Flyback/flyback%20DCM2.html). Digest then ask if you still need help.

Comment: These voltage arrows... something is really off about \$V_D\$... Perhaps breakdown?

Answer (score 2):

You don't get to pick R.  That's the load the converter needs to be able to power.

C needs to be big enough to that its voltage doesn't drop too much between pulses.

Since you haven't said anything about current, frequency, nominal voltage, and allowable voltage variation, there is no way to define "too much".

Comment: Olin Lathrop please take any example for flyback converter to find such values capacitor? I am a beginner please guide how to deal with this. ok here is data supply voltage is 24V and output voltage is 12 V switching frequency is 100kHz please tel me the formula for calculating all duty cycle, Capacitor, magnetising inductance, Resistances for flyback converter.